# Use domain name to forward tow HTTPS request on two local server

Tags: port-forwarding, dns-hosting

I have an static IP that set to domain edbazar.com
I have two server one of these server has Microsoft exchange 192.168.0.50 and another has rdweb 192.168.0.60
I create sub domain rdweb.edbazar.com and mail.edbazat.com.
I want that when any one type   it connect to 192.168.0.60
And when type
 it connect to 192.168.0.50
With out adding any port in url.
I can solve this problem with port forwarding but I want use domain with out any port in url.
Please help me

Comment: You need what's commonly called a reverse proxy

Comment: @HBruijn can you get me an name or Link to download

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reverse-proxy

Comment: @HBruijn with nginx only can forward port 8000---> 80 but I want to forward dns to another computer, please help me